# CUDA 6.5: Device Synchronize returns 30

Tags: cuda

I have the following problem:

- On my tower computer, mounting a nVidia GTX690, using CUDA 8.0 with VS 2015 I wrote a project (fully working :) )
- I tried to import that on my (very old) laptop with the following configuration:

  - nVidia GT330M, CUDA capability 1.2, compatible to CUDA 6.5
  - Visual Studio 2013 Express
  - nVidia Driver 341.74

As you can imagine, the project compiles just fine, but every time I try to execute a kernel (with whatever configuration of block/thread) and then synchronize the device returns the error code 30. This corresponds to an unknown internal error.

Is my GPU too old that it cannot run not even a simple  kernel (e.g. a single call to cudaMalloc, for 16Kb buffer)?

Or is that a mismatch between the maximum nVidia driver version and the CUDA version?

If it can help, here's the output of nvidia-smi:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 341.74     Driver Version: 341.74         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 330M    WDDM  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   52C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    972MiB /   979MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I try to get the cudaProperties that's a simplified version of what I get:

```
MapSMtoCores for SM 1.2 is undefined.  Default to use 128 Cores/SM
Name                   : GeForce GT 330M
Total Global Memory    : 1073741824
Total Constant Memory  : 65536
Multi-Processor Count  : 6
Compute Mode           : 0
Concurrent Kernels     : 0
Shared Memory Per Block: 16384
Registers   Per Block  : 16384
Max Threads Per Block  : 512
Max Threads Dims       : (512 | 512 | 64)
Max Grid Size          : (65535 | 65535 | 1)
```

Is the `compute_mode` equal to 0 worrying? Or as well a 0 concurrent kernels?

Finally, it probably doesn't make any difference, but both systems (tower and laptop) run on Windows 10 64 bits, and the code is compiled in Visual Studio only for 64 bits.

[EDIT]
cudaMalloc and cudaFree works fine. The simplest kernel that I'm trying to run is:

```
__global__ void Init(float* __restrict__ ptr, size_t sz, float value)
{
    unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int step = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    for (size_t i = tid; i < sz; i += step)
        ptr[i] = value;
}
```

called with `Init<<<1, 1>(ptr, 100, 1.0f)`

Comment: oooh.. forget about it, cuda 8.0 support specific devices, i dont think it will work...

Comment: Uhm.. I haven't compiled any code specific for CUDA 8. It's a very simple wrapper of CUDA (alloc, free, etc..) in C#, just for learning the basics, I doubt it's related to the CUDA 8 version specifically!

Comment: good luck with that...

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to post the answer once it's solved ;)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Yes, it's within the kernel! and I'm compiling using the nvcc that comes with the CUDA 6.5 installer, with the flag compute_12, sm_12.

Also, the installer said that the CUDA samples counld't be installed!

Comment: Whoever downvoted, cared to explain why? Is it an obvious question? If it is, can you shoe me the answer please? I clreadly stated what the question is, and what I attempted so far, I don't see why you should downvote instead of answer..

Comment: (Not the downvoter, but) that's hard to debug. There have been some "M" cards that did not support CUDA or needed special drivers, but not sure whether this applies here. Also: Can you run **any** CUDA program? Maybe you can download one of the samples manually and try to compile it, just to rule out that it's a general hardware/driver issue...

Answer (score 1):

If anyone of you ever comes to my very same issue here's what I had to do:

- Reinstall CUDA 6.5 (CUDA samples didn't work)
- Manually download CUDA Samples
- Copy configuration setup and run in **32 bit**, as 64 bit are not supported by deviceswith capability <= 1.3
- Remove any reference to **double** precision routines, as these are not supported
- Substitute `size_t` with `unsigned int` when dealing with pointers
- Remove any reference to `cudaMallocHost` as apparently pinned host memory wasn't supported before 1.3

Comment: Devices with compute capability < 2.0 most certainly work with 64 bit host operating systems. Always have done.

Comment: So it must be the specific combination GT330M + Windows 10. I can't run the CUDA Samples on 64 bit, but only on 32 bit